# How to retain values in Jqgrid

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jqgrid

I have drop down lists in Jqgrid, when I select a certain value in the drop down and click on some other row the grid show the default value again and not the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the JSON object of data then only it will save the value .What happens is it actually reverts back to previous value so after you modify the JSON and drop down then only it will persist